# Why visual studio 2022 complains about unknown CSS class property bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created a razor page web app template project in visual studio 2022.

I am adding some bootstrap CSS class.

here is my html:

```
<form  method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="searchTerm"  value=""/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The template load bootstrap by default in the layout page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn"
```

crossorigin="anonymous">

I tried referencing the CDN one even

However vs complains about not knowing these classes

form-group, input-group-btn, glyphicon glyphicon-search

Any reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Is the `href` value for your local copy of Bootstrap correct? I use LibMan in Visual Studio and the default directory for Bootstrap is `twitter-bootstrap` instead of `bootstrap`. Therefore, the `href` for me is `~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`.